# Best way to update data in mysql online database

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have an online sql database with a few tables for `users` `matches` and `bets`. When I update the result of any game, I need the status of all bets containing that game in the bet table to be updated. So for example if I update game `8` with the result `home win` I need all bets which have game `8` in them to be updated as either `lost`, `won` or still `open`.

The way I do this currently is that when the user turns on my android app, I retrieve all the information about the games and all the information about the user's bets using asynctasks. I then do some string comparisons in my app and then I update the data in my database using another asynctask. The issue is that this wastes a lot of computation time and makes my app UI laggy.

As someone with minimal experience with php and online databases, I'd like to ask is there a way to carry out these things in the database itself either periodically (every 3 hours for example) or whenever the data in the `games`table is changed using a php file for example which is automatically run?

I tried looking for some kind of `onDataChanged` function but couldn't find anything. I'm also not sure how to make a php file run and update data without getting the app involved.

Another idea I had was to create a very simple app which I wouldn't distribute to anyone but just keep on my phone with an update button which I could press and trigger a php file to carry out these operations for all users in my database.

I would appreciate some advice on this from someone who has experience.

Thanks :).

Comment: sounds like you want: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: How are you updating the results in your database now? That process is an obvious place to add the updates to the other tables.

Comment: Literally by hand using phpmyadmin

Comment: @mankee Should we assume that your app is connecting directly to the database and executing queries? If so, what's to stop an attacker doing something similar and executing something malicious? It sounds like you need to learn some server-side scripting so that you can validate requests and develop some methods for having the server do these updates.

Comment: my app connects to php files on the server which then execute the queries, meaning he would have to know the exact links to the php files to be able to do anything malicious

Comment: @mankee So where did these PHP files come from? There's an awful lot about this project you haven't made clear. Since you seem to have some PHP capability, write a script that takes the updates you want to apply and applies them, and updates _all_ the tables that need to be updated at the same time. This really seems to be a non-problem.

Comment: I wrote php files which take data from my app and update the database with it. I haven't ever wrote files which are directly activated in the server itself or can carry out the computation required which I currently do using java. I think the optimal way for me to do this is to use a seperate app on my own phone since I'm pretty confident on how to do this. That way after I update the games in my online database, I will simply run the app on my phone once and it will automatically be updated for all the users.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily execute php script periodically if your hosting provider supports script executors like Cron.

About updating game status multiple times, first check tables engine. If you are using engine like InnoDB you can create relationship between those tables, so updating status of one row will affect all connected to them.